# Hasura remote schema Inconsistent object: Duplicate remote field 'collections'

Tags: graphql, schema, hasura

I try to add multiple remote schema to hasura and i got the error bellow.

The first schema is  : http://host.docker.internal:3000/shop-api

The second schema is : http://host.docker.internal:3000/admin-api

It seems that hasura found the field "collections" in the 2 schemas and refused to add the second schema.

Why hasura did not isolate each schema with its name ?

Please any help.

Thank you

```
[
    {
        "definition": {
            "definition": {
                "timeout_seconds": 60,
                "url": "http://host.docker.internal:3000/admin-api",
                "headers": [],
                "forward_client_headers": true
            },
            "remote_relationships": [],
            "name": "Vandure-admin",
            "permissions": [],
            "comment": ""
        },
        "reason": "Inconsistent object: Duplicate remote field 'collections'",
        "name": "remote_schema Vandure-admin",
        "type": "remote_schema"
    }
]
```